# Android: Hand drawing on top of ImageView

Tags: android, xamarin.android, imageview, drawing, landscape-portrait

I want to implement hand drawing feature on top of an `ImageView`.

This is my layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutEditImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutEditImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayoutEditImageToolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewEditImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/light_blue" />

            <mobileclient.Droid.HandDrawingCanvasView
                android:id="@+id/canvasViewEditImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            ........> //this is the toolbar, etc
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I follow [Multi-Touch Tracking in Android example](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/ApplicationFundamentals/FingerPaint/) for the `HandDrawingCanvasView` Class:

```
public class HandDrawingCanvasView: View
    {
        // Two collections for storing polylines
        Dictionary<int, HandDrawingPolyline> InProgressPolylines = new Dictionary<int, HandDrawingPolyline>();
        List<HandDrawingPolyline> CompletedPolylines = new List<HandDrawingPolyline>();

        Paint paint = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);

        public HandDrawingCanvasView(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public HandDrawingCanvasView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) :
            base(context, attrs)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        void Initialize()
        {
        }

        // External interface accessed from MainActivity
        public Color StrokeColor { set; get; } = Color.Red;

        public float StrokeWidth { set; get; } = 2;

        public void ClearAll()
        {
            CompletedPolylines.Clear();
            Invalidate();
        }

        // Overrides
        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent args)
        {
            // Get the pointer index
            int pointerIndex = args.ActionIndex;

            // Get the id to identify a finger over the course of its progress
            int id = args.GetPointerId(pointerIndex);

            // Use ActionMasked here rather than Action to reduce the number of possibilities
            switch (args.ActionMasked)
            {
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                case MotionEventActions.PointerDown:

                    // Create a Polyline, set the initial point, and store it
                    HandDrawingPolyline polyline = new HandDrawingPolyline
                    {
                        Color = StrokeColor,
                        StrokeWidth = StrokeWidth
                    };

                    polyline.Path.MoveTo(args.GetX(pointerIndex),
                                         args.GetY(pointerIndex));

                    InProgressPolylines.Add(id, polyline);
                    break;

                case MotionEventActions.Move:

                    // Multiple Move events are bundled, so handle them differently
                    for (pointerIndex = 0; pointerIndex < args.PointerCount; pointerIndex++)
                    {
                        id = args.GetPointerId(pointerIndex);

                        InProgressPolylines[id].Path.LineTo(args.GetX(pointerIndex),
                                                            args.GetY(pointerIndex));
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEventActions.Up:
                case MotionEventActions.Pointer1Up:

                    InProgressPolylines[id].Path.LineTo(args.GetX(pointerIndex),
                                                        args.GetY(pointerIndex));

                    // Transfer the in-progress polyline to a completed polyline
                    CompletedPolylines.Add(InProgressPolylines[id]);
                    InProgressPolylines.Remove(id);
                    break;

                case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
                    InProgressPolylines.Remove(id);
                    break;
            }

            // Invalidate to update the view
            Invalidate();

            // Request continued touch input
            return true;
        }

        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.OnDraw(canvas);

            // Clear canvas to white
            paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);
            paint.Color = Color.Transparent;
            canvas.DrawPaint(paint);

            // Draw strokes
            paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
            paint.StrokeCap = Paint.Cap.Round;
            paint.StrokeJoin = Paint.Join.Round;

            // Draw the completed polylines
            foreach (HandDrawingPolyline polyline in CompletedPolylines)
            {
                paint.Color = polyline.Color;
                paint.StrokeWidth = polyline.StrokeWidth;
                canvas.DrawPath(polyline.Path, paint);
            }

            // Draw the in-progress polylines
            foreach (HandDrawingPolyline polyline in InProgressPolylines.Values)
            {
                paint.Color = polyline.Color;
                paint.StrokeWidth = polyline.StrokeWidth;
                canvas.DrawPath(polyline.Path, paint);
            }
        }
    }
```

And these are the results:
[image: portrait]
[image: landscape]

As you could see, I could draw even outside the image (the blue area is the `ImageView` background). How to limit drawable area to only within the boundary of the picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to find the bounds of the drawn image within the `ImageView` that displays it.

Once you have that, you can discard any touch event that goes outside that area. Pseudo code of your `onTouchEvent` would be somewhere in the lines of:

```
    Overrides
    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchEvent){

        if(!isInsideDesiredArea(touchEvent.getX(), touchEvent.getY()){
            return false;
        }

        ... //same with what you have now
    }
```

To find the bounds of a drawable drawn by an `ImageView`, you can use `Rect r = ImageView.getDrawable.copyBounds()`, which will write the bounds in `r`.

Finally, `isInsideDesiredArea(...)` will look like this:

```
private boolean isInsideDesiredArea(float x, float y) {
    //get the image view
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_imageview_id);

    //get the transform it applied on the drawable
    float[] imageViewTransformMatrixValues = new float[9];
    imageView.getImageMatrix().getValues(imageViewTransformMatrixValues);

    //get the bounds of the drawn drawable, before the transforms are applied to it, and in local coordinates
    Rect drawableRect = imageView.getDrawable().copyBounds();

    //get the drawable scale & translation, from its matrix
    float scaleX = imageViewTransformMatrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
    float scaleY = imageViewTransformMatrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];
    float translationX = imageViewTransformMatrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float translationY = imageViewTransformMatrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

    //compute the actual bounds of the drawable, within the image view, in image view local coordinates
    Rect actualImageRect = new Rect();
    actualImageRect.top = Math.round(translationY + scaleY * drawableRect.top);
    actualImageRect.left = Math.round(translationX + scaleX * drawableRect.left);
    actualImageRect.bottom = Math.round(translationY + scaleY * drawableRect.bottom);
    actualImageRect.right = Math.round(translationX + scaleX * drawableRect.right);

    //finally check if the touch events are within the rectangle defined by the drawable
    return actualImageRect.contains((int) x, (int) y);
}
```

I tested it on a small sample project, and it works fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried your solution and the bounds area is shifted as you can see here: https://imgur.com/a/d1IvO
and then, after two/three times drawing, there will be an exception in `InProgressPolylines.Add(id, polyline);`

Comment: ah ok. you're getting the touch events already in the view's local coordinate system. i'll update my answer. i cannot comment on the crash though, that  must be somewhere within your code

Comment: check the new version of the code, should be ok now. the previous version also translated the events vertically, presuming the events were in the screen's coordinate system, in order to match the coordinate system of the image view. but since your onTouchEvent is of the ImageView itself, this translation was not necessary

Comment: I tried your new version now and it works. Do you perhaps know how to preserve the hand drawing when the device is rotated? Right now, if I rotate the device, the hand drawing is gone.

Comment: you either need to save your points, and then draw them again after the device is rotated, either obtain a Bitmap of your HandDrawingCanvasView. To obtain a Bitmap of you view, you can use the views drawing cache. If you have it enabled, you can use `Bitmap handDrawing = myHandDrawingView.getDrawingCache()`, then save the Bitmap in the bundle you get in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle myBundle)` with `myBundle.putParcelable("drawing", handDrawing)`. Then, after the rotation, in `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedState)` get it back via `Bitmap bitmap = savedState.getParcelable("drawing")`